# How to normalize and model state in NGXS for nested arrays?

Tags: angular, ngxs

I just hit a wall with attempting to update state on a deeply nested array object and from researching it I need to normalize my state.

The data structure I am working with is as follows:

```
   sportTypes: SportType[
  sportTypeObj{
     leagues: League[
        leagueObj{
              teams: Team[
                 teamObj{} <== this array needs updating
                ]
           }
      ]
   }
]
```

so basically SportType object has an array property of type League[], and each league object has an array property of type Teams[]. I need to update teams array on a specific league. I am not too sure how to structure my `SportTypeStateModel` to reflect this data structure.

This is what I had before:

```
`export interface SportTypeStateModel {
  sports: SportType[];
  loading: boolean;
  error?: any | null;
}`
```

But there with this, there is no easy way of updating Teams array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative could be to have 3 (or 4) entity storages. But it doesn't become easy as expected.

- `SportTypeStateModel` : with inside { sportTypeIds: string[] }
- `SportType` : with inside { leagueIds: string[] }
- `League` : with inside { team: Team[] }

Comment: I was almost thinking of creating separate states for sports, leagues and teams. That way I can avoid having one giant file where I have all of my CRUD actions for each type. Would it make sense to do that? that is what you were referring to in your first sentence right? Each state will will like `{entities: byID: { 'stringID': the type}, allIDs: []}` I think that should work right?

Comment: Yes. that was the idea. But instead of creating your own entities store, check the [Entity](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity) from NGRX. There is a lot a features that will facilitate the work.

Comment: hmm I already implemented NGXS, I might consider NGRX in my next project.

Comment: Ah sorry! I though that was with NGRX. But the idea is still the same behind :)